# Line weight in Canvas object changes during scaleX animation?

Tags: apache-flex, animation

I am currently working with a Canvas object on which I am drawing curves using the curveTo() function of the canvas' corresponding Graphics object.

The following animation is being performed on the Canvas object's scaleX attribute.

```
<mx:AnimateProperty property="scaleX" fromValue="1" toValue=".5" duration="1000" />
```

At present, this transformation is also scaling the line weight down by some arbitrary value. Is there any way to perform a scaleX transformation on the Canvas without it modifying the line weight of the lines drawn in the canvas? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your line weight is set to the .1 or pen stripe.  Try setting the line width to 1.

Comment: Hi Nate, actually the lines can be anywhere from weight ~60 to less than one, and in all the cases it appears as though the weight changes when we scale them. (the line weights are all a percent width of a larger line, so their total weight adds up to the width of the large line)